# Vue Js Axios Response Not able to access this.data

Tags: vue.js, axios

Vuejs axios get will not update myData from response.

```
export default {
        data(){
            return {
                myData:'foo'   
            }
        },

        beforeMount() {

                    axios.get('/api/data').then((response)=>{ 
                    this.rowData = response.data;
                    this.myData=this.rowData;
                });
              }

        console.log(this.myData) //prints foo instead of this.rowData value


}
```

I expect this.rowData output

Answer (score 0):

`axios.get()` returns a `Promise`, sou you should `console.log()` it after assignment, when `Promise` is resolved. Till `Promise` is not resolved value will still the same.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
       myData: "foo"   
     }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    axios.get("/api/data").then(response => { 
      this.rowData = response.data;
      this.myData = this.rowData;
      console.log(this.myData)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I can console.log(this.myData) just fine within the response scope but outside, console.log(this.myData ) is null.

```vue